# Two tests that wont pass when ran together but pass independently

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

Issue:

I have two test cases each pass when ran independently but when ran together the first one ran will pass and the second one ran will fail. What is even more interesting is if I switch the which test is first (NUnit runs in alphabetical order so adding an 'A' to the test method name does the trick)

Here is some code that reproduces my issue. It is clearly related to the JavaScript manipulation but I dont know why.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;

namespace POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Category("test")]
    public class Test
    {
        public IWebDriver driver { get; set; }
        string listingUrl = "http://cgi.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=110194475127#ht_1235wt_1139";
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void setUp()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }

        [Test]
        public void test_CounterTest()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(listingUrl);
            WaitForElementVisible(By.CssSelector("#but_v4-28binLnk"));  //  Buy it now button selector
            Assert.IsTrue(IsElementPresent(By.CssSelector("#ngvi_desc_div > div > div > div.aucCounter")), "Counter was not found on page");
        }

        [Test]
        public void test_ScrollingGallery()
        {
            var listingTitleUsed = "Test Listing Do Not Bid Or Buy";
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(listingUrl);
            WaitForElementVisible(By.CssSelector("#but_v4-28binLnk"));  //  Buy it now button selector
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            var script = "document.getElementById('csgGallery').style.display='block';";
            js.ExecuteScript(script);
            WaitForElementVisible(By.CssSelector("div[class=csgTitle]"));
            var listingName = getSudoElementContent("div[class=csgTitle]", ":after");
            listingName = listingName.Replace("/", "");
            listingName = listingName.Replace("\"", "");
            Assert.AreEqual(listingTitleUsed, listingName);
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void tearDown()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }

        public string getSudoElementContent(string selector, string cssEvent)
        {
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            string script = String.Format("return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('{0}'),'{1}').getPropertyValue('content')", selector, cssEvent);
            string content = (String)js.ExecuteScript(script);
            return content;
        }

        public void WaitForElementVisible(By element)
        {
            var attempts = 0;
            while (attempts < 2)
            {
                try
                {
                    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
                    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(element));
                    break;
                }
                catch (WebDriverException)
                {
                    attempts++;
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    attempts++;
                }
            }
            if (attempts >= 2)
            {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate " + element.ToString());
            }
        }

        public bool IsElementPresent(By by)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.FindElement(by);
                return true;
            }
            catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            catch (WebDriverException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS When I test this functionality during nightly tests I use a new listing for each test case.

When `test_ScrollingGallery` is ran second I get this exception

```
Test Name:  test_ScrollingGallery
Test FullName:  POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.Test.test_ScrollingGallery
Test Source:    C:\git\auctiva-webdriver\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\Test.cs : line 32
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:02.311

Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
   at POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.Test.test_ScrollingGallery() in C:\git\auctiva-webdriver\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\Test.cs:line 38
Result Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Cannot read property 'style' of null
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

And when I run `test_Countertest` second I get this error

```
Test Name:  test_CounterTest
Test FullName:  POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.Test.test_CounterTest
Test Source:    C:\git\auctiva-webdriver\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\Test.cs : line 24
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:02.34

Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByCssSelector(String cssSelector)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<CssSelector>b__1c(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.Test.test_CounterTest() in C:\git\auctiva-webdriver\POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite\Test.cs:line 27
Result Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#ngvi_desc_div > div > div > div.aucCounter"}
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Comment: What is the error message? Which line?

Comment: Updated question to include the exceptions